# What techniques may I use for mocking interactions with TaskFactory.FromAsync()?

Tags: c#, mocking, task-parallel-library, rhino-mocks

I am attempting to unit test the interactions of my application and the asynchronous `HttpWebRequest` methods and am wondering how to simulate the call of the asynchronous callback.  For instance, consider the following code:

```
Task.Factory
    .FromAsync<Stream>(wr.BeginGetRequestStream, wr.EndGetRequestStream, null)
    .ContinueWith(SomeDelegate);
```

In this case `wr` is an object that essentially wraps HttpWebRequest.  I can stub and set expectations on this object in the unit test, but I can not think of a way to create the signal that would otherwise call `EndRequestStream`.  Without this signal, the unit test blocks indefinitely waiting for the task to complete, which will never happen.

I can create interfaces and proxies for `Task` and `TaskFactory`, then set expectations at that level, but I am hoping there is something less involved.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you change the type of `wr` to expose a `GetRequestAsync` method that returns a `Task<Stream>`? That way you can mock it so that it returns a task from a `TaskCompletionSource` which you can prod within your test. I've done something similar with a class myself to test a composition block, and it worked well. The tests are interesting to write, in terms of all the different things that can happen, but it works...

Comment: This seems to be the best approach as I control the interface.  The method you suggested is also a good replacement for the asynch-methods already on the interface.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I got queston right, if you want to simulate Event Raise you can use following syntax:

```cs
// wr should be Mock
// EndRequestStream  - event
wr.Raise(x => x.EndRequestStream += null, 
              this, 
              new EventArgs(...));
```

Do not forget to put right `EventArgs` instance.

Comment: In my example, `EndGetRequestStream` is a method.  It is equivalent to `HttpWebRequest.EndGetRequestStream`, which is called after the network device driver asynchronously notifies you of the completion corresponding "begin" call.